# Python csv: preserve headers when writing to file

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a simple function that acts depending on the number of rows of the CSV the user is supplying, by either adding or removing columns:

```
def sanExt(ifpath, ofpath):
    with open(ifpath, "rb") as fin, open(ofpath, "wb") as fout:
        csvin = csv.reader(fin)
        csvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=",")
        fline = csvin.next()
        if len(fline) == 33:
            for row in csvin:
                row.insert(10, "NULL")
                csvout.writerow(row)
            print "AG"
        elif len(fline) == 35:
            print "AI"
        elif len(fline) == 36:
            print "AJ"
        else:
            print "Unknown"
```

I've stopped at the first `if` statement, just to make sure my code works. The column is properly added in this case, but the headers are missing.

How do I make sure every row is written to the file, not just `[1:len(rows)]`?

Is my method the proper pythonic way to do the desired job?

Comment: When reporting an exception (TypeError), the traceback is always helpful. Failing that, telling us what line raised the exception is better than what you given us.

Comment: Quoth the docs: "Note that unlike the DictReader class, the fieldnames parameter of the DictWriter is not optional. Since Python’s dict objects are not ordered, there is not enough information available to deduce the order in which the row should be written to the csvfile." and see http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need `csv.DictReader` for access via column names, then the traditional solution is based around something like the following:

```
with open('in.csv') as fin, open('out.csv', 'wb') as fout:
   csvin = csv.reader(fin)
   csvout = csv.writer(fout)
   try:
       header = next(csvin)
       csvout.writerow(header)
   except StopIeration as e:
       pass # empty file - either handle, or we'll just continue and drop out of loop

   for row in csvin:
       csvout.writerow(row) # do some real work here...
```

Comment: Just deleted my answer, which was exactly what you propose. I had it by trial and error, not code-fu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the csv.DictReader, csv.DictWriter and its [writeheader()](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) method to handle the header line with little excess code.